# Using bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx outside of blender

Tags: export, .fbx, operator

I'm writing script for Shotgrid to Blender connection. I have a problem with using one operator.

Inside my script, it's fails  on this line:

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=path, use_selection=True, bake_anim_use_all_actions=False)
```

The error I get is

```
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_editable_objects'
```

My script works well inside Blender. But when I Run it through Shotgrid, it doesn't work.
I assume it's because when I logged `bpy.context.area` it returned 'None'. So how I can get this work, do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: While the area thing can be confusing, do you need an area for export_scene? It should not be context sensitive.

Comment: Well, I found an answer, here:,
https://github.com/diegogarciahuerta/tk-blender
In my case, operator override helped. Diego ( author of the toolkit I linked) wrote this function:
def get_view3d_operator_context():
It outputs dictionary one can use as operator override ^^